# Swift Storageで画像をアップロードしようとして　import FirebaseStorage　しているがType 'Storage' has no member 'storege'というエラーが出てしまった

Tags: swift

画像を保存しようとして
let storageRef = Storage.storege().reference().child("profile_image").child(fileName)と設定したらType 'Storage' has no member 'storege'というエラーが発生しました。
Firebaseのモジュールは以下の通りimport しているのですが何か間違っていたらご指摘頂けたらと思います。

import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseStorage

Answer (score 0):

単純なスペルミスが原因のように見えます。stor**e**ge ではなく stor**a**ge

**誤:**

```
let storageRef = Storage.storege().reference().child("profile_image").child(fileName)
                         ~~~~~~~
```

**正:**

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_image").child(fileName)
```

Comment: 投稿してすぐ気づいたのですが、それよりも早く回答がついて返答の素晴らしく早い事に感動しております。早々の回答ありがとうございました。